# Separating a String of Text into Separate Words in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings, parsing, natural-language-processing

Occasionally, we want to do a rudimentary parsing on English text; we separate the text into separate words.

```python
# INPUT STRING 
istring = "she sat down beside the child and sang a melody like a wind in summer
blowing softly."

# OUTPUT LIST
olist = ["she", "sat", "down", "beside", "the", "child", "and", "sang", "a", "melody", "like", "a", "wind", "in", "summer", "blowing", "softly", "."]
```

I wrote some code, but the implementation is ugly.

I was hoping to make `make_special_iter` more readable to human beings.

## Code

```python
class StringPartitioner:
    def __init__(self, istring:str):
        self._istring = istring
        self._it = self.make_special_iter(istring, self._char_to_class)

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self._it)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    @classmethod
    def make_special_iter(cls, istring:str, char_to_class):
        assert(isinstance(istring, str))
        try:
            it         = iter(istring)
            buffer     = list()
            everything = list()

            ch = next(it)
            prev_class = char_to_class(ch)
            buffer.append(ch)

            for ch in it:
                everything.append(ch)
                cur_class = char_to_class(ch)
                if cur_class != prev_class:
                    word   = "".join(buffer)
                    buffer = list()
                    # print("word".ljust(30), repr(word))
                    yield word
                buffer.append(ch)
                prev_class = cur_class
            yield "".join(buffer)
        except StopIteration:
            return

    def _char_to_class(self, ch:str):
        big_letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        sml_letters = big_letters.lower()
        letters = big_letters + sml_letters
        if ch in letters:
            return ord("A")
        return ord(ch)

    def __str__(self):
        return type(self).__name__ + "(" + repr(self._istring) + ")"
```

## A Test Case

```python
# Input for test one 

itest1 = """she sat down beside the child and sang a melody like a wind in summer blowing softly; a melody from wild woods and grassy plain; a melody of valleys loved by children. She sang a melody now lost, but for dreams; a melody
along the edges of oblivion; now flashing like stellars of the night,
a glimpse of some golden moment, now passing swiftly out of remembrance again.
Her melody danced upon the green like little shining feet. Then her song, faded into stillness."""

# correct output for test one 
otest1 = [
    'she',
    ' ',
    'sat',
    ' ',
    'down',
    ' ',
    'beside',
    ' ',
    'the',
    ' ',
    'child',
    ' ',
    'and',
    ' ',
    'sang',
    ' ',
    'a',
    ' ',
    'melody',
    ' ',
    'like',
    ' ',
    'a',
    ' ',
    'wind',
    ' ',
    'in',
    ' ',
    'summer',
    ' ',
    'blowing',
    ' ',
    'softly',
    ';',
    ' ',
    'a',
    ' ',
    'melody',
    ' ',
    'from',
    ' ',
    'wild',
    ' ',
    'woods',
    ' ',
    'and',
    ' ',
    'grassy',
    ' ',
    'plain',
    ';',
    ' ',
    'a',
    ' ',
    'melody',
    ' ',
    'of',
    ' ',
    'valleys',
    ' ',
    'loved',
    ' ',
    'by',
    ' ',
    'children',
    '.',
    ' ',
    'She',
    ' ',
    'sang',
    ' ',
    'a',
    ' ',
    'melody',
    ' ',
    'now',
    ' ',
    'lost',
    ',',
    ' ',
    'but',
    ' ',
    'for',
    ' ',
    'dreams',
    ';',
    ' ',
    'a',
    ' ',
    'melody',
    '\n',
    'along',
    ' ',
    'the',
    ' ',
    'edges',
    ' ',
    'of',
    ' ',
    'oblivion',
    ';',
    ' ',
    'now',
    ' ',
    'flashing',
    ' ',
    'like',
    ' ',
    'stellars',
    ' ',
    'of',
    ' ',
    'the',
    ' ',
    'night',
    ',',
    '\n',
    'a',
    ' ',
    'glimpse',
    ' ',
    'of',
    ' ',
    'some',
    ' ',
    'golden',
    ' ',
    'moment',
    ',',
    ' ',
    'now',
    ' ',
    'passing',
    ' ',
    'swiftly',
    ' ',
    'out',
    ' ',
    'of',
    ' ',
    'remembrance',
    ' ',
    'again',
    '.',
    '\n',
    'Her',
    ' ',
    'melody',
    ' ',
    'danced',
    ' ',
    'upon',
    ' ',
    'the',
    ' ',
    'green',
    ' ',
    'like',
    ' ',
    'little',
    ' ',
    'shining',
    ' ',
    'feet',
    '.',
    ' ',
    'Then',
    ' ',
    'her',
    ' ',
    'song',
    ',',
    ' ',
    'faded',
    ' ',
    'into',
    ' ',
    'stillness',
    '.'
]
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're writing your own instead of using NTLK? (https://github.com/nltk/nltk) The difference is that NTLK doesn't return the spaces, but, do you need those?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I think you meant to write `NLTK`, but instead, you wrote the letters out of order as `NTLK`. Note that `NLTK` is a sub-sequence formed from the string of text `NATURAL LANGUAGE TOOL KIT` by deleting 21 letters. In general, the name of every python library every written in a sub-sequence of a fully-formed English phrase. Perhaps, some day, people can write `import natural_language_tool_kit` or write  `import nltk`. People who are in a hurry write, `import nltk`. However,  `import natural_language_tool_kit` is more self-documenting or self-explanatory.

Answer (score 7):

While your program is functional and solid, there are plenty of improvements to be made.

---

### How I would solve it.

A better way to solve this would probably be:

```py
import re

test_string = "she sat down beside the child and sang a melody like a wind in summer blowing softly."
print(re.split("(^A-Za-z)", test_string))
```

Outputs:

```py
['she', ' ', ' sat', ' ', ' down', ' ', ' beside', ' ', ' the', ' ', ' child', ' ', ' and', ' ', ' sang', ' ', ' a', ' ', ' melody', ' ', ' like', ' ', ' a', ' ', ' wind', ' ', ' in', ' ', ' summer', ' ', ' blowing', ' ', ' softly', '.']
```

This program splits the string by anything not in the alphabet, and *includes* the delemeters.

---

### Code review

**The many variables**

Having lots of variables decreases readability, and some variables, like `everything` don't seem to be doing much (I assume it was left over from development). I'd try to cut down on the amount of variables you're using, and make sure you're remaining ones are well named (e.g. `it` to `string`, etc.). However, the following changes will help you with that.

**Your use of `_char_to_class()`**

While it is clever the way you've used `_char_to_class()` to test if letters are in the alphabet, a more direct approach would be just to do:

```py
ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

if ch.lower() in ALPHABET:
    ...
```

or even just:

```py
if ch.isalpha():
    ...
```

**Your complex structure and generator expressions**

```py
for ch in it:
    everything.append(ch)
    cur_class = char_to_class(ch)
    if cur_class != prev_class:
        word   = "".join(buffer)
        buffer = list()
        # print("word".ljust(30), repr(word))
        yield word
    buffer.append(ch)
    prev_class = cur_class
    yield "".join(buffer)
```

While your current structure is clever, it may just be easier to do something like:

```py
word = ""
for ch in it:

    if ch.isalpha():
        word += ch

    else:
        yield word
        word = ""
    ...
```

**Your assert block**

```py
assert(isinstance(istring, str))
```

While it is good to have an assert block where you've put it, the correct syntax for assert is `assert <bool>` or `assert <bool>, <error-message>` (no parentheses), so you'd have to do:

```py
assert isinstance(istring, str)
```

However, I would just raise an error here instead.
:

```py
if not isinstance(istring, str):
   raise TypeError("Cannot use make_special_iter with non-string.")
```

**Your use of `list()`**
In places like:

```py
it = iter(istring)
buffer = list()
everything = list()
```

while it is technically correct to use `list()`, it's [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790860/and-vs-list-and-dict-which-is-better) to use `[]` for an empty list:

```py
it = iter(istring)
buffer = []
everything = []
```

**Your use of a class**

While you *can* use a class for your `make_special_iter`, it isn't recommended. You could just use a method. And as the name `make_special_iter` wouldn't be as descriptive any more, I'd use something like `partition_string` instead.

**Your use of generators**

While it's easy (and slick) to use generators, I'd do something like:

```py
words = []
word = ""
for ch in it:
    if ch.isalpha():
        word += ch

    else:
        words.append(word)
        word = ""
    ...

return words
```

But you don't need to (you could just use `list()`).

---

### Full code

**With generators**

```py
def partition_string(string):
    if not isinstance(string, str):
        raise TypeError("Cannot use make_special_iter with non-string.")

    word = ""
    for ch in string:
        if not ch.isalpha():
            yield word
            yield ch
            word = ""

        word += ch
```

```py
test_str = "she sat down beside the child and sang a melody like a wind in summer blowing softly."
print(list(partition_string(test_str)))
```

**With lists**

```py
def partition_string(string):
    if not isinstance(string, str):
        raise TypeError("Cannot use make_special_iter with non-string.")

    words = []
    word = ""
    for ch in string:
        if not ch.isalpha():
            words.append(word)
            words.append(ch)
            word = ""

        word += ch

    return words
```

```py
test_str = "she sat down beside the child and sang a melody like a wind in summer blowing softly."
print(partition_string(test_str))
```

Both these give the same output:

```py
['she', ' ', ' sat', ' ', ' down', ' ', ' beside', ' ', ' the', ' ', ' child', ' ', ' and', ' ', ' sang', ' ', ' a', ' ', ' melody', ' ', ' like', ' ', ' a', ' ', ' wind', ' ', ' in', ' ', ' summer', ' ', ' blowing', ' ', ' softly', '.']
```

---

These changes would make your code much easier to read. (I'd still use the code with the regex though.)

I hope this is useful, please comment for any improvements.

Comment: That regular expression isn't inclusive enough. There are English words with accents, like "naïve" or other non-English letters like "façade". A regex like `([^\p{L}]+)` using the `regex` module would probably be a better idea. The `\p{L}` indicates an Unicode letter. https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html <-- Here's a list of other classes that maybe supported. https://pypi.org/project/regex/ <-- This is the `regex` module.

Answer (score 5):

### `_char_to_class`

First of all, let's take a look at your `_char_to_class` method.

```
    def _char_to_class(self, ch:str):
        big_letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        sml_letters = big_letters.lower()
        letters = big_letters + sml_letters
        if ch in letters:
            return ord("A")
        return ord(ch)
```

`big_letters` and `sml_letters` and indeed `letters` are all members of the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) stdlib module as `string.ascii_uppercase`, `string.ascii_lowercase` and `string.ascii_letters` respectively. So we don't need to define that ourselves.

The method also does not depend on `self` at all, and would be better as a `@staticmethod`, which says that this is a function which doesn't depend on its class, but it joined to it out of convenience.

Also, this method seems to be just reproducing the [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) method (possibly in conjunction with `str.isascii`) so I'm not sure we need it at all.

### `make_special_iter`

This method is declared as a `@classmethod` and yet doesn't rely on the class at all. A class method is a method which uses properties of the class, but not the instance, this uses neither and is probably a `@staticmethod` as it's currently written. In standard usage, it is taking the `istring` and `char_to_class` from `self`, and therefore should be converted into a regular method. Replacing `istring` with `self._istring` and `char_to_class` with `self._char_to_class`.

I also think the name `make_special_iter` is not terribly helpful as it doesn't reflect what's happening. `split_words_punct` might be more informative or `split_by_char_class` or similar. Examining it in more detail, however, what is actually happening is a `group_by` explicitly for strings.

You always want to minimise the scope of `try` blocks, as this makes debugging easier. In your case the only line which could raise a `StopIteration` is the call to `next` at the start. So we can make the `try` much tighter. In fact, I believe the only reason that that would fail is if the `istring` is empty. So why not check that first:

```
if not istring:
    return
```

Is much simpler and much more clear what we're checking and that also means we don't need a separate `next` call at all, we can set `prev_class` initially to an invalid value `None`, this also means we don't need to explicitly create the `iter` over string.

I also don't know why you are building `everything` when it appears to be unused? We can get rid of that.

That leaves us with:

```
    def make_special_iter(self):
        buffer = []
        prev_class = None

        for ch in self._istring:
            cur_class = self._char_to_class(ch)
            if cur_class != prev_class and prev_class is not None:
                word = "".join(buffer)
                buffer = []
                yield word
            buffer.append(ch)
            prev_class = cur_class
        yield "".join(buffer)
```

### `__iter__`

Your `iter` method exhausts itself on its first call, which probably isn't what you want.

```
>>> X = tmp.StringPartitioner('Hello world')
X = tmp.StringPartitioner('Hello world')
>>> for i in X:
...     print(i)
...

Hello

world
>>> for i in X:
...     print(i)

>>>
```

You should probably make your `__iter__` method reset your `self._it`.

```
    def __iter__(self):
        self._it = self.make_special_iter()
        return self
```

Though I'm not sure we want that either (see the end)

### `__init__`

Finally, we should move our `assert` into when we create our `StringPartitioner`, however in my experience it is more common to do it via an `if-raise` rather than `assert` in Python

```
if not isinstance(istring, str):
    raise TypeError('Cannot construct StringPartitioner from non-string')
```

### Overall

After all this, we're left with:

```
from string import ascii_letters as alphabet

class StringPartitioner:
    def __init__(self, istring: str):
        if not isinstance(istring, str):
            raise TypeError('Cannot construct StringPartitioner from non-string')
        self._istring = istring
        self._it = self.make_special_iter()

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self._it)

    def __iter__(self):
        self._it = self.make_special_iter()
        return self

    def make_special_iter(self):
        buffer = []
        prev_class = None

        for ch in self._istring:
            cur_class = self._char_to_class(ch)
            if cur_class != prev_class and prev_class is not None:
                word = "".join(buffer)
                buffer = []
                yield word
            buffer.append(ch)
            prev_class = cur_class
        yield "".join(buffer)

    @staticmethod
    def _char_to_class(ch: str):
        if ch in alphabet:
            return ord("A")
        return ord(ch)

    def __str__(self):
        return type(self).__name__ + "(" + repr(self._istring) + ")"
```

However, I would argue that this probably doesn't warrant being a class at all. `make_special_iter` is just a generator which takes a `str`ing and a constant function. I would say it stands alone perfectly well.

```
def split_on_char_class(string, comparison_func=char_to_class):
    buffer = []
    prev_class = None

    for ch in string:
        cur_class = comparison_func(ch)
        if cur_class != prev_class and prev_class is not None:
            word = "".join(buffer)
            buffer = []
            yield word
        buffer.append(ch)
        prev_class = cur_class
    yield "".join(buffer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Samuel, Would you consider an existing library, such as [spaCy](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101)? SpaCy has a [lemmatizer](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html), which may do more then you need, depending on what you want to do with the words. Maybe you could have a poke around [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com), or [other parts of stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38763007/how-to-use-spacys-lemmatizer-to-get-a-word-into-basic-form), to see what the NLP folks are doing.

Comment: `@Simon Crase` When you write, "`see what the NLP folks are doing`" am I correct in surmising that your sentence is equivalent in meaning to "`see what the Natural Language Processing folks are doing`"?

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon Yes

Answer (score 1):

What you've implemented seems similar to `itertools.groupby`. Generally in python you're encouraged not to reinvent the wheel, so maybe you could try `[list(g) for k, g in groupby(text,lambda x:x.isalpha())]`? This also can ouput generators if needed.